# What material should be used behind a sink and range in the kitchen?

Tags: walls, kitchens, waterproofing

I am getting ready to demo my kitchen to the studs in a couple weeks. 
I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions for alternate materials to use other than "green" board (moisture resistant drywall) behind the sink, dishwasher, stove area behind the base cabinets.

In speaking to a local contractor a year or so ago then mentioned some other material but can't recall what it is.

I have a galley kitchen with a peninsula at one end. the sink, dishwasher, and stove are in the center in listed order.

Comment: Do you mean behind the base cabinets, or just above the counter? Are you going to be tiling or putting some type of backsplash up? Is there a specific reason you don't want to use drywall?

Comment: Check your local building regulations. According to Australia building regulations, you must have a fire-resistant wall next to your cook top. When we had ours installed, they simply cut out the plaster to a width of a metre behind the cooktop and added the special plaster board. The splashback was then installed over this.

Answer (score 1):

[Hardibacker](http://www.jameshardie.com/homeowner/backerboard.shtml) makes a board that can be used instead of drywall (its the same thickness). tiles can be put right onto it. Thats in the US anyway.